# Vue.JS using class for element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I try to give v-if="seen" for some class but it doesn't work obviously...

My code:

```
<div class="item" v-if="seen">item 1</div>
<div class="item" v-if="seen">item 2</div>
<div class="item" v-if="seen">item 3</div>

var item = new Vue({
   el: 'div.item',
   data: {
       seen: true
   }
});
```

In JavaScript I could do :

```
var item = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++){
    item[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

How must I do in Vue.js ? Thanks

Comment: Your use of v-if is correct. You don't want to be setting up separate Vue instances for each div.item, though; that should be a single element containing the other divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a v-for and setup the data to use an array.

Try something like this:

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="myItem in items" class="item" v-if="myItem.seen">{{myItem.name}}</div>
</div>

var app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
       items : [{
           seen: true,
           name: 'item 1'
       },
       {
           seen: false,
           name: 'item 2'
       },
       {
           seen: false,
           name: 'item 3'
       }]
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: No problem :) Have fun coding

Answer (score 2):

The way Vue is designed, it should be ideally done like so:

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="item" v-if="seen">item 1</div>
    <div class="item" v-if="seen">item 2</div>
    <div class="item" v-if="seen">item 3</div>
</div>

var app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
       seen: true
   }
});
```

Comment: The problem is how I do for apply seen:true for only one item and false for others then ?

Comment: check my answer... it should do exactly what you need.

Comment: You would need different variables controlling each of them, then.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to achieve what you want. Example of one of them:

```
<div is="app">
  <div class="item" v-if="!seen.includes('item1')">
    item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item" v-if="!seen.includes('item2')">
    item 2
  </div>
  <div class="item" v-if="!seen.includes('item3')">
    item 3
  </div>
</div>

var item = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    seen: [
      'item1',
      'item3'
    ]
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var item = new Vue({
   el: 'div.item',
   data: {
       isSeen: true
   },
    computed:{
     seen:()=>this.isSeen;
    }
});
```

or you could use v-show or v-class